# What is this "triple not equal" operator and how can I type it?

Tags: javascript

I have attached a screenshot with a red circle. What is this operator? How can I type it?

[image: code with a circled "triple not equal" symbol]

Comment: An example of a coding font with ligatures: [JetBrains Mono](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/#ligatures)

Comment: this is actually a valid question, but probably a dupe

Answer (score 2):

### That is the not-identical / strict-inequality operator

It is written like so: [`!==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality)

It returns true if the operands are different in value *or* type.

The reason it looks like it does in your editor is because you have font ligatures turned on. Font ligatures may look nice, but they create exactly this problem: they disguise the actual characters of the source code, leading to confusion.

VS Code lets you turn them off, and you should. Go to settings and search for "ligatures".